# Probability density function of the sum of uniform is a polynomial

Tags: probability

I have to proof that the pdf of the sum of n uniform in (0,1) it's an n degree polynomial, but I can't use characteristic function or the Irwin-Hall Distribution. I supouse it has to be proven with conditional probability.

Comment: What is the pdf for $n=2$?

Comment: I disagree with the statement of your problem. I believe that the pdf is piecewise $n-1$ degree polynomials. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin–Hall_distribution#Special_cases).

Comment: You are totally right, thank you, thats all I need.